# Enum value fetch?

Tags: java, enums

how to fetch the value of the enum dynamically from the tag[] array specified.

```
public enum TagName {

    NAME("ASTON", null), ADDRESS("WER", null);

    private String tagNameValue;
    private String defaultValue;

    public String getTagNameValue() {
        return tagNameValue;
    }

    TagName(String header, String defaultValue) {
        this.tagNameValue = header;
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    public String getDefaultValue() {
        return defaultValue;
    }

}

public class MainExe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String tag[] = { "NAME", "ADDRESS" };

        String data = TagName.ADDRESS.getDefaultValue();
        System.out.println(data);
        // i want to fetch the value from the enum based on the tag value passed
        // dynamically.

        // something like this
        for (int i = 0; i < tag.length; i++) {

            String data = TagName.tag[i].getDefaultValue();
            System.out.println(data);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Enum.valueOf(Class<T>, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String-) or rather implicitly defined `valueOf(String)` method, which returns the constant with the given name.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tag.length; i++) {
    String data = TagName.valueOf(tag[i]).getDefaultValue();
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

Comment: got it thanks,for (int i = 0; i < tag.length; i++) {
      String data = TagName.valueOf(tag[i]).getTagNameValue();
      System.out.println(data);
  }